# When exactly does Sirius shine into the queen's chamber of the Great Pyramid?

Tags: star, observational-astronomy

I read that Great Pyramid was built to resonate with Sirius by aligning an airshaft that connected to queen's chamber. That is, the light of Sirius going through the shaft would be able to shine into the queen's chamber.

When exactly star Sirius shines into the queen's chamber of Great Pyramid?

Comment: https://spacemath.gsfc.nasa.gov/SED11/P9Pyramids.pdf may or may not be helpful

Answer (score 6):

The premise of this question is wrong: [the "Sirius" shaft was not designed to point towards Sirius](http://www.cheops.org/startpage/thefindings/thelowernorthshaft/lowernorth.htm). Most of the shafts bend (sometimes several times), making it impossible for the light of a star to shine through. Furthermore, the angle of the shaft is not constant, making it possible for the shaft to be pointed towards tens of different stars, depending on which portion of the shaft you want to look at.

The Sirius shaft that leads to the queen's chamber faces south. It is at a 39.6° angle and the width of the window that it provides is 0.18°.

Due to [precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_precession), the maximal elevation of stars changes over time. Based on [this document](https://spacemath.gsfc.nasa.gov/SED11/P9Pyramids.pdf), Sirius would have been visible through the shaft between 2355 BC and 2295 BC. This is after the construction period of the pyramid (around 2550 BC), putting the idea that the shaft was "built to resonate with Sirius" even more in question.

Answer (score -4):

Just because there isn't a straight line doesn't mean the shaft isn't an arrow pointing at Sirius. I'd argue they made it imperfect on purpose. It's meant to only draw a line from the inner hole to outer hole using your mind. Ancients didn't have robots to drive up the shafts. It's meant to draw your minds eye to Sirius and the star next to it in Orion. Perhaps if those two stars aren't where they're supposed to be, it's meant to alert us. This isn't the only megalith that points to Sirius & Orion. Orion is an arrow or a finger pointing at Sirius. They want us to watch Sirius & Orion. If u were sending a message 24,000 years into the future that can't be hidden from the public or destroyed, how would u do it? It would need to be very simple & very large. You can't deface a shaft built into a giant pyramid. So the knowledge can't be hidden. Y'all are overthinking it imo. They wanted no decoration because this isn't a celebration. It's a warning. A space weather warning perhaps.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support your ideas by more credibility? As-is it's unfounded speculation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).